# Gas limit set dangerously high

Tags: solidity, transactions, gas

When sending ETH to my deployed crowdsale contract seems to always complaining gas on metamask too high and then transactions "cancelled" on etherscan.

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x043acaa777f3e08d0b25d48c899a681a7a17db37#code

I was able to send ETH last night before 5am GMT if you see the transactions.

Would anyone be able to shine some light ?

Comment: What is your question? I see that some transaction failed but others were accepted correctly. If you have a specific problem with a transaction you can indicate it otherwise it is not clear your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out my setBonus 2nd if case will never meet and will call revert .
that was why.

Comment: Yeah most of time, this issue is related to wrong solitidy code or revert/break condition.